# Where do I find custom made maps / campaigns for Elemental: War of Magic?

Tags: elemental-war-of-magic

Been a few weeks now since Elemental: War of Magic released, are there any singleplayer maps / campaigns out there already?

Google doesn't turn up anything useful.

Comment: This is off-topic, as per our FAQ. Specifically, "Catalogues (listing games that fit specific criteria or are like an existing game) and Shopping advice and recommendations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there are quite a few user-generated maps on the developer's site at http://www.elementalgame.com/mods/type/maps/sort/downloads.